# How to create an XML with multiple attributes?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to have the exact xml using c# with multiple attributes. So, please quick response will be apprecatiable.

```
<EDMAG>
<edelcall calltype="contact" customerid="4026805">
<contactsout calltype="contact">
<contactout calltype="contact" customerid="4026805"></contactout>
</contactsout>
</edelcall>
</EDMAG>
```

I tried working on it but attributes were automatically converted into new xml elements.

Comment: "I tried working on it" - what did your code look like? *Always* show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Before posting any question on SO, always mentioned what you'd tried and what was your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating xml with LINQ to XML, there is overloaded constructor of [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302741.aspx) which accepts collection of objects as element's content:

```
 public XElement(XName name, params Object[] content)
```

You can pass any number of attributes or other elements as content of one you are creating (see samples at MSDN). Sample of creating xml element with multiple attributes:

```
var edelcall = new XElement("edelcall", 
                        new XAttribute("calltype", "contact"),
                        new XAttribute("customerid", 4026805));
```

It will produce

```
<edelcall calltype="contact" customerid="4026805" />
```

I believe you've got the idea and can now construct xml of your desired format.

Suggested reading: [LINQ to XML Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)

Comment: XML can be converted in C# class using special paste feature provided by Visual Studio 2012. Simply copy your well formatted XML and create .cs file and use Edit>>Special Paste>> Paste XML As Classes. Its so simple and time saving.